# Filtering posts based on three taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, ajax, taxonomy

I've built a filterable post listing where the user can filter based on two taxonomies, this is working but I now want to add a third taxonomy to the filter, but I think the logic I'm using isn't very efficient.

Here's my code for the two taxonomy filter. If I was to add a third taxonomy using this approach I would need to add an If/Else block for each combination, but there must be a better way of doing this?

```
function filter_ajax() {
$category = $_POST['category'];
$sector = $_POST['sector'];
$size = $_POST['size'];
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

if(isset($category) && isset($sector)) {
    $args["tax_query"] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'project_category',
        'terms' => array($category)
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sector',
            'terms' => array($sector)
        )
    );
} else if(isset($sector)) {
    $args["tax_query"] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sector',
            'terms' => array($sector)
            )
    );
} else if (isset($category)) {
    $args["tax_query"] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'project_category',
            'terms' => array($category)
            )
    );
}
```

I'm passing in the term id for the taxonomies: category, sector and size. Sometimes these will be unset if the user hasn't selected a term in a particular taxonomy.

Is there a better way of structuring this request without having to add more if/else statements?

Comment: You're right, it can be structured better by having the tax query as its own variable then appending to it when needed, and assigning at the end, HOWEVER, the entire approach is suboptimal. This code and the custom query and args can all be replaced and streamlined by putting parameters in the URL, e.g. `yoursite.com/thearchive/?project_category=1&sector=2&thertax=3` then WordPress would do everything for you, and you'd just need a form with the `GET` method and inputs with the same names as the URL params. You could even use Rewrite rules to map the URL to the params e.g. `1/2/3`

Comment: Keep in mind though this isn't a discussion forum, you need to ask a specific question that can be concretely answered. You need to be able to mark an answer, not just as the best answer or most helpful/informative, but as definitively correct for all people in a factual sense. I'm struggling to identify how that could be done here without it just being code golf or reassurances, it seems more like a discussion

Comment: Thanks.Tom. I think my question is probably too vague and, as you say, is more of a discussion. I was mainly asking in case there was a best-practice means of implementing this functionality as it must be so common, but if there isn't then this would be more of a discussion. I'll have a look at the URL parameter approach, thanks for your idea on that.